# Messed the SSL certificate files of my VM

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

I am trying to create a new SSL certificate with `openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt`.

I am getting this output error :

```
Can't open /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf for reading, No such file or directory
140188383974784:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:74:fopen('/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf','r')
140188383974784:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:81:
Generating a RSA private key
...................................+++++
....................................................................+++++
writing new private key to '/etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key'
-----
unable to find 'distinguished_name' in config
problems making Certificate Request
140188383974784:error:0E06D06A:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no conf or environment variable:../crypto/conf/conf_lib.c:272:
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

The `/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf` file (which should be a symlink to `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`) is missing, so openssl can't read its config. I'm not sure how you managed to delete it, but I think the most surefire solution is to reinstall the `openssl` package with the following command (I'm assuming you're using a Debian-based system):

```
sudo apt install openssl --reinstall
```